# Google Maps: How to prevent InfoWindow from shifting the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3.

I noticed that if I have a map marker near the edge of my map border ... that if I click the
marker icon so that the InfoWindow will display, my entire map shifts so that the
markers InfoWindow is centered.

I don't want my map to shift.

**Question**: How do I prevent the map from shifting when InfoWindows are near the end of the map border (which causes the InfoWindow by default to center & shift the map)?

Answer (score 64):

Since you are using v3, you can simply prevent the infoWindow from shifting the map with the `disableAutoPan` option, as in the following example ([API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps disableAutoPan Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

   <div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.44, -122.14);
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Test',
      disableAutoPan: true
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Test Marker'
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: disableAutoPan]

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called [disableAutoPan] of agm-marker-info, making it false will not shift your map InfoWindows which are located near the edge of map border.

```html
<agm-marker-info [disableAutoPan]="false">
    <b> Marker Info: "A" </b>
</agm-marker-info>
```