# Auto Open Infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am loading multiple markers for 2 branches. I am not able to automatically open infowindow on load of the page?

```
    var locations = [
  ['<strong>Info</strong><br /> Address', 40.004257, -105.253425, 2],
  ['<strong>Info</strong><br /> Address', 39.999326, -105.257662, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.00, -105.24),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    icon: "images/favicon.png",
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }
```

Anything wrong with the code? Is there a fix to auto open infowindow?

Comment: On which marker should it open? You add a listener to each marker that will open the infowindow on click. Anyway you have multiple markers and a single InfoWindow object. That same object can't be opened on multiple markers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done to load the infoWindows when you load the page.

```
function initMap() {
var locations = [
  ['<strong>Info</strong><br> Address', 40.004257, -105.253425, 2],
  ['<strong>Info</strong><br> Address', 39.999326, -105.257662, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.00, -105.24),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:locations[i][0]
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
 infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

after the for loop.

maybe this one could help.

[Google maps open info window by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239372/google-maps-open-info-window-by-default)