# Why does not InfoWindow show content on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to open google map info window by default. InfoWindow is opening but it does not show the content inside. However, it shows the content on clicking marker.

```
var contentString =  '<div  style="color:#323232;">'+
                      '<div style=" float:left;">'+
                            '<ul>'+
                                '<li><a href="#">info@asda.com</a></li>'+
                                '<li> <a href="#">+971 12342134</a</li>'+
                                '<li><a href="#">Location Map</a></li>'+
                                '<li><img src="'+gm_url_bm+'-ft-dection.png" /></li>'+
                            '</ul>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div style=" float:right; margin-right: 15px; line-height: 25px;">'+
                      '<img src="logo-internal.png" /><br /><br />'+
                      'Dubai, United Arab Emirates,<br />P.O. Box 1234124</div>'+
                    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

I [followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239372/google-maps-open-info-window-by-default) this answer but it does not work for me.

I attached [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeQeC.png) for reference. Can anyone guide me how can i fix it? I would like to appreciate. Thank You

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c2dhq8pn/) (after I fix the javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gm_url_bm is not defined`)

Comment: @geocodezip I defined this variable but i didn't mention in the question `var gm_url_bm = 'http://exy.com/demo/exy/wp-content/themes/exy-child/images/gm/';`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]