# Google Maps Api: set center of the map to an offset in pixels?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this might be a weird question …

I'm using the google maps api to embed custom maps on my webpage. I pass the `lon/lat` coordinates along to a function and a map is drawn with this point "centered" in the middle. (my map frame is like 300px high, so the marker is approx at 150px)

Since I'm also using custom `infoWindows/Boxes` I'd like to move the center of the map a bit down.

I know I could set a seperate center in `lon/lat` coordinates but that's not what I'm looking for. This would require for every map to pass along the coordinates of the marker and the coordinates of the center I'd like to have.

I'd like it to be more simple.

Is it possible to move the center of the map just a few pixels down?

Like `center: +30px,` :)

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]); // latitude and longitude
    var options = {
    zoom: zoom,
    //center: c,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scrollwheel: scroll,
    streetViewControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {  
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could do that? Any oder tricks or ideas?

Comment: The answer to this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488999/google-maps-how-to-prevent-infowindow-from-shifting-the-map

Comment: Well, in my case the window is already visible on page-load. I don't have to click the marker so `autoPan` doesn't really affect my problem.

Comment: autoPan refers to the map being panned to accommodate the infoWindow when it opens, so it should make no difference if the marker is already visible. It is easy however to shift the center by a few pixels, but I don't have the time right now. I'll post a piece of code later, if the question is still unsolved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

call the panBy-method of the map

```
mapObject.panBy(0,30)
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: HaHa, good solution!(+1). I was going to use the projection and do something unnecessarily complicated. Need more coffee! ;-)