# Offset google map center with panby

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm sure this is a stupidly simple question but I'm struggling with it :S

I want to offset my map center using `panBy` as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14378636/1648623) but I'm not entirely sure where to place `mapObject.panBy(0,30)` or if I need to change the bit that says mapObject

Here is my code so far:

```
function initialize()
{

var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $entrylatlng;?>,
    zoom:14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);

var contentString = 
        if( gmapsstring.gmapaddresspostcode.length > 0 ) {
        contentString += '<p>' + gmapsstring.gmapaddresspostcode + '</p>';
        };

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
});

var point = new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $entrylatlng;?>;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      map: map
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
infowindow.open(map,marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Sorry for the reams of code, I'm not sure what needs to be included. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems like you pasted the initialize function twice. To keep track and a clean question you should maybe remove the duplicate, to allow others to quickly get an overview without having to read unnecesary code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can start panning directly after you initialized the map. So your initialize function might look like this:

```
function initialize(){
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $entrylatlng;?>,
    zoom: 14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
  // start panning
  map.panBy(0, 30);

  var contentString = 
    if( gmapsstring.gmapaddresspostcode.length > 0 ) {
    contentString += '<p>' + gmapsstring.gmapaddresspostcode + '</p>';
  };
  /**
  * the rest of your code goes here
  * ...
  */
}
```