# disableAutoPan in angular-google-maps not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm currently using angular-google-maps v 2.1.0 in my project.
Everything works fine, but when I'm  using markers with windows to appear on click I'm running in an AutoPan issue. The map scrolls into position, but shouldn´t.

In the documentation there is an option to set disableAutoPan to true. But it doesn't get any options set to it.

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="focusmarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
    <ui-gmap-windows  show="show" options="{ disableAutoPan : true}">
        <div ng-non-bindable>{{content}}</div>
    </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Even max-width or any of the other options don´t have any effect on the window.

Has anyone a suggestion regarding this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Hope to hear from you

Greetings

Michael

Comment: What do you mean by "markers with windows to appear on click"? Are you talking about clicking on info windows? if so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488999/google-maps-how-to-prevent-infowindow-from-shifting-the-map

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug with Angular Google Maps. I confirm that using:

```js
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true
});
```

works well.